# Angular 1 filter array not updating

Tags: angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter

I really wish I was doing something wrong here. Please see my js bin. http://jsbin.com/benewetewe/1/edit?html,js,output

Some user-story:

1. When I check items and click "archive", it filters all "bought:true" away.
2. When I click the "show history", it shows back all items whether its "bought:true" or not.
3. But I noticed a problem, when I add new item in the list and click "archive", the new item is hid even if it's not yet "bought:true".
4. But If I try to select & de-select the new item, it will now be part of the hid items when "archive" is clicked.

Anything I missed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small typo in your code, which caused the problem :

```
$scope.toBuyAddItem = function (toBuyItem) {
    toBuyItem.bough = false;  /* <-- typo : change .bough to .bought */
    $scope.toBuyList.push(toBuyItem);
    $scope.toBuyItem = {};
};
```

Add a letter 't' to fix all your problems ;)

Comment: thanks, knew it i'm doing something not right..darn it *_*